# Filter array based on category of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to filter an array based on the category of its objects. So for example,

Take this array:

```
const base = [
0: {id: 1, category: 'earth'},
1: {id: 2, category: 'moon'},
2: {id: 3, category: 'earth'},
]
```

And return a filtered array with only the category 'earth'.

```
const filtered = [
0: {id: 1, category: 'earth'},
1: {id: 3, category: 'earth'},
]
```

I have tried using .filter() to no avail...

Comment: You want to sort it or just filter it?

Comment: Possible duplicate question about filtering by object property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
const categories = [
  {id: 1, category: 'earth'},
  {id: 2, category: 'moon'},
  {id: 3, category: 'earth'},
];
const result = categories.filter(({ category  }) => category === "earth");
```

Comment: I don't think the name `category` suits here. It's  not an array of categories, as entries with the same category have different IDs. You can avoid naming it by destructuring the object: `({ category }) => category === "earth"`